# Selenium cannot find element by id on supreme website python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-3.5

I'm making a bot that buys items from the supreme website using the Selenium library for Python 3.5. The bot can successfully add an item to the cart, but in the checkout process, selenium throws an error whenever it attempts to send keys to an input element found by the `find_element_by_id()` method. Here's a simplified version of the code that throws the error:

```
from selenium import webdriver
d = webdriver.Chrome()
# First it adds an item to the cart
d.get('http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/tops-sweaters/vxdau6b3t/km1pzdca3')
d.find_element_by_name('commit').click()
# Then it goes to the checkout
d.get('https://www.supremenewyork.com/checkout')
name_box = d.find_element_by_id('order_billing_name')
# This is the line that throws the error
name_box.send_keys('name goes here')
```

Here's the full error message:

```
File "error.py", line 7, in <module>
    name_box.send_keys('name goes here')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 479, in send_keys
    'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 628, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.
  (Session info: chrome=66.0.3359.181)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528157 (4429ca2590d6988c0745c24c8858745aaaec01ef),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.3 x86_64)
```

When I replace the line `name_box = d.find_element_by_id('order_billing_name')` with the line `d.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='order_billing_name']")` the code works as intended. However, this isn't a viable solution as when the element is found this way, the `send_keys()` method is very slow.

Comment: Check id is in frame or not

Comment: I have updated my chromedriver as @DebanjanB and @yong suggested. It is now version 2.39, but I still get the same error as before. The code from @stanjer answer works, but because the element is being found by css selector, it is just as slow as finding it by xpath. As far as i can tell, the only difference between `find_element_by_id('order_billing_name')` and `find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='order_billing_name']")` is that in the second, the program is also making sure the element found is an input. Could this have to do with the problem? if so, is there a faster way to search for it?

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to do it correctly (of course there are a lot of things to improve, but I tried to keep it short. Please check the comments inline

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# First it adds an item to the cart
driver.get('http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/tops-sweaters/vxdau6b3t/km1pzdca3')

# wait until cart link is available
add_to_cart = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[name=commit]"))
)
# add to cart
add_to_cart.click()

# wait until checkout link is available
go_to_cart = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#cart:not(.hidden) a.checkout"))
)

# Then it goes to the checkout
go_to_cart.click()

# wait until name input is available
name_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.order_billing_name"))
)

# we can't select pseudo elements with css selector, but we can click on an element 
# above it, which is defined in "name_input", and emulate keypresses,
# which are intended for the selected ("click()") element only

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(name_input).click().send_keys("hey 123").perform()

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

According to chromedriver [change note](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads), please upgrade your chromedriver to 2.37 or 2.38 which is more compatible with chrome 66.